# $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-x e^{-i\pi\sin(\theta)} - y e^{-2i\pi\sin(\theta)}} d\theta$: Exact or Upper Bound

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

Hello Math Stack Exchange community,

I have encountered a challenging integral that I am struggling to simplify and express in terms of special functions, particularly Bessel functions. The integral I am working with is:

$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-x e^{-i\pi\sin(\theta)} - y e^{-2i\pi\sin(\theta)}} d\theta
$$

I have attempted to compute this integral numerically and then simplify it, but I'm having difficulty finding a closed-form expression.

Interestingly, I found a similar integral that has been simplified in terms of Bessel functions in a previous discussion on Math Stack Exchange: [link to previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857504/int-02-pi-frac1-pi-e-x-e-j-pi-sin-theta-d-theta). However, the integral in that discussion is not exactly the same as mine.

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any insights, techniques, or strategies that could help me simplify this integral and express it in terms of Bessel functions. Additionally, if anyone has encountered a similar integral or has experience working with parametric integrals involving exponentials, your expertise would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: In the spirit of the linked question, the integral can be written as $$2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^k  J_0(\pi(n+k))$$ Though that's just as ugly as the integral.

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes Thanks a lot could you provide the steps or hints for this generalization? also I think it is very similar to Schlömilch's Series.

Comment: also it is look like Kapteyn series.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I simply expanded $e$ via its power series and split the integrals up into their respective positive and negative $sin(\theta)$ counterparts.