# $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \theta^m \exp\left(-\sum_{k=1}^{K} x_k e^{-ik\pi\sin(\theta)}\right) d\theta$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, special-functions, harmonic-analysis

### Introduction

Seeking insights on generalizing the integral solution from

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp\left(-\sum_{k=1}^{K} x_k e^{-ik\pi\sin(\theta)}\right) d\theta$$[Solution is here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4859311/frac1-pi-int-02-pi-exp-left-sum-k-1k-x-k-e-ik-pi-sin-the)

to

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \theta^m \exp\left(-\sum_{k=1}^{K} x_k e^{-ik\pi\sin(\theta)}\right) d\theta$$

### Questions

1. **Simplification Methods:** Are there techniques to simplify the analysis?
2. **Solution Insights:** Can the first integral's solution guide solving the second? especially for $m = 1$ and $m = 2$.
3. **Literature References:** Any similar forms or strategies discussed in literature?

### Context

This inquiry stems from research in wave propagation and Fourier series, where such integrals are common.

### Request

Appreciate any guidance or references. Thank you!

Comment: I think after inserting forier series for $\theta^m$ we can solve this problem using past solution.