# Finding Closed-Form for Series Involving Bessel Function and Partitions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, bessel-functions

I'm investigating a series that intertwines Bessel functions, partitions, and multinomial coefficients, aiming to derive a closed-form expression or deepen understanding of its properties. The series in question is:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} J_0\left(\pi\sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ r_1 \geq 0, \ldots, r_K \geq 0 \\ r_1 + \ldots + r_K = n}}^K k \cdot r_k\right) (x_1 + \ldots + x_K)^n
$$
**for determined $K$.**

Context:
The expression combines a Bessel function
$J_0$
​
with a sum over integer partitions and a multinomial expansion. I'm exploring using the Taylor expansion of $e^{-z}$
and properties of the product of Fourier series coefficients to simplify or understand this series better.

Questions:

How can the Taylor expansion of
$e^{-z}$
be applied here, especially given the exponential and Bessel function interaction?
Could the product of Fourier series coefficients provide insights into the sum's behavior, considering the series' combinatorial nature?

Attempts: I've looked into isolating components and examining their properties but am struggling with integrating these into a coherent approach.

Seeking: Any insights, references, or strategies that could aid in understanding or simplifying this complex series.

Thank you for any guidance!

### Multinomial Expansion Definition

The **multinomial expansion** refers to the expansion of a power of a sum that includes more than two terms. For a given expression of the form ($(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_K)^n$), the multinomial expansion can be expressed as:

$$
(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_K)^n = \sum \binom{n}{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_K} x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} \cdots x_K^{n_K}
$$

Comment: It looks like you want to simplify the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4859311/evaluation-of-frac1-pi-int-02-pi-exp-left-sum-k-1k-x-k-e)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash yes, but it is another problem. Is this forbidden?